# way of implementing links in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a project I am doing in rails. I want to implement this sort of links

{user} has {action} on {file} in {project}

each of the words wrapped by curly braces are entities in my system (models). how do I implement saving these changes in the project and how do I get all of the changes from the database and display them to the user?

I am using rails 2.3.8 if it matters

example of the links I need to display (image)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some plugins available to keep track of activities in models:

- https://github.com/grosser/record_activities
- https://github.com/linkingpaths/acts_as_scribe
- https://github.com/face/activity_streams

I normally use acts_as_scribe, it's the simplest of them.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [acts_as_audited](https://github.com/collectiveidea/acts_as_audited). It works very well. It saves all your changes on a model in the form of a hash, so using it becomes as easy as

```
audit = Audit.first #just for example
```

In your view

```
<%= link_to User.find(audit.user_id), user(:id => audit.user_id) %> has
<%= audit.action %>
```

Of course you will have to customize how your messages will finally appear. And of course its better not to use find methods in your view. I've used it here just for illustration purposes.